# Exported OBJ to Procreate is imported with UV coordinate overlapping

Tags: export, uv-image-editor

A very simple 3D blender model.  Two cubes.  I use a Boolean difference to create what is basically a square donut.  Exporting that file as an obj to be used in Procreate.  I’ve merged, checked for overlapping, spaced all faces, made sure scale is 1, no materials, no textures, just the generic cubes.  Confirmed that it is manifold.

Is this something peculiar to Procreate or am I missing something very simple.

Thanks,  Mick

Answer (score 0):

I think I found how to do this - you need to UV unwrap your model. I got it to work by selecting all the faces or edges in *Edit mode*, hit the <kbd>U</kbd> key to bring up the UV menu and select *Smart UV Project*. Then if you export as an OBJ it should work in Procreate. In my example I also had to delete, not just hide, the objects I used for my Boolean modifiers.

[image: screenshot of UV context menu]

Comment: Well it seems for